# Removing low Battery Indicator in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, remove, battery, warning

I have recently installed Ubuntu on a mini pc with a zx8350 cpu.  The installation recognizes the CPU as a laptop CPU and automatically displays the "low battery" indicator even though the machine is actually connected and powered by AC power.  I have seen some suggestions for older distros to remove the indicator-battery program which do not work for this updated version.  I plan on using these devices in an enterprise roll-out and would like to have a method to disable the low battery warning on the top bar.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should give more details about the specific PC hardware you are using.